# Rails ActiveResource undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created two applications.

In first application, in PublicItem controller I render json data from Item controller like this:

```
  def index
    render json: Item.all
  end
```

When I access this controller via web browser, I see jason data
I want to use ActiveResource to display this data in my other application. In the other application I have created Activeresource model to communicate with application like this:

```
class Item < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "http://localhost:3000/public"
end
```

In my Form model, I have created item method like this:

```
  def item
    @item ||= Item.find(item_id) unless item_id.blank?
  end
```

in my view _form I have created collection secelc where I would like to see all the records like this:

```
<p>
  <%= f.label :item_id %>
  <%= f.collection_select :item_id, Item.find(:all), :id, :name %>
</p>
```

I have also created migration for adding item_id to Forms model.

But I am getting error:

```
undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

25: 
26: <p>
27:   <%= f.label :item_id %>
28:   <%= f.collection_select :item_id, Item.find(:all), :id, :name %>
29: </p>
30: 
31:
```

Can anyone tell me why am I getting this error?

Comment: Can you try Item.all instead of Item.find(:all)?

Comment: Nothing changes, I am still getting this error

Comment: Seems you don't have items, or you ar wrongly setting your site url `http://localhost:3000/public`. I would expect something like `http://localhost:3000/items`

Comment: Can you show your routes file?

Comment: but when I enter localhost:3000/public in my browser I get the forlowing json data:
[{"name":"TestName","created_at":"2013-05-07T09:22:51Z"}]

Comment: In my Items controller sign_in is required, that's why I created PublicItems controller where I render Items from the Items controller. All items in jason format are accessible via localhost:3000/public where are only json data

Comment: @juanpastas here is my routes match '/public' => 'public_items#index'

Comment: Can you see log for requests being made, try this: `ActiveResource::Base.logger = Rails.logger`, I tried it in console. You should see something like `...#<File:/~/my_app/log/development.log>...` which is server log file. Then you can enter Items.all to see in server log where request is going.

Comment: Seems that logger step is not needed.

Comment: post the whole stacktrace

Comment: If I try to connect to Items controller, I get an authentication error because have set-up authentication for Items. To avoid that, I created PublicItem controller where I parse the json data but I can't understand why I am getting this error. Without authentification I can get to the Items straight forward but it doesn't work for me..

Comment: I don't have model defined for PublicItems controller. It is used just to give json data